# Bad Request on PHP Curl request to SOAP web service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, curl, soap

Here is the method I'm using:

```
$xml_data = 'XML data';

$headers = array(
"POST /ws_autos.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: (web service url)",
"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
"SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/(web service method)\"",
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)
);

$url = (web service url)?wsdl;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);

$reply = curl_exec($ch); 



$xmli = new SimpleXMLElement($reply);


print_r($reply);

print_r($xmli);
```

I'm getting a Bad Request error without clarification upon excecution. I've checked the XML body for mistakes but there seem to be none, and there's nothing out of place in the header as far as I know.

I've tried using SoapClient but I can't find any documentation/resources on building the XML body with the amounts of nesting going on here.

Comment: curl is not a socket client, most of them headers are not going to work, and POSTFIELDS is expecting an array or query string not a chunk of XML

Comment: I figured it might work since it was voted as an answer on another question on the site, and also because I'm only starting to learn about SOAP and web services in general so I don't know a great deal. Do you know where I could find any documentation that would help me get into the right direction with this specific issue?

Comment: I would use a lib which generates a model from the wsdl, though there are manual ways to do it, https://www.google.com/search?q=soap+client+php+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @LawrenceCherone actually you're wrong, if you want your HTTP POST body to be a raw XML file, then send the XML file as a string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and set the `Content-Type` header to XML, he's doing that part correctly. - it's only if you want to use the `Multipart/form-data`-format that you set CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your xml is corrupted, **STRICTLY** speaking.

DOMDocument::loadXML is a very strict XML parser, and it says this:
`Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document in Entity, line: 2 in /in/EOrYe on line 43`

because: 
[image: the newline corrupts your XML]

your `<?xml` declaration is not the first thing in your XML. the very first thing in your XML is a newline, THEN comes your `<?xml`. you can either remove the newline, or you can replace

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
```

with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($xml_data));
```

also get rid of

```
"Content-length: ".strlen($xml_data)
```

because libcurl will automatically add it for you if you don't, and libcurl won't make any mistakes about it (unlike you, if you do `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, trim($xml_data));`  then the length will change because of the trim, so pretty much *always* let curl do it for you.)

also get rid of `"POST /ws_autos.asmx HTTP/1.1"`

because 1: curl will add this header for you.
and  2: you don't know here if curl is going to use HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2 , if curl decides to use HTTP/2 here, you'll corrupt the request.. (and curl DOES support HTTP/2 now, even tho it requires nginx libraries iirc and many servers' curl builds don't yet support it, but you wouldn't want your script to magically stop working the moment your curl build supports HTTP/2, would you? no, you wouldn't.)

also get rid of `"Host: demo.caledoniaseguros.com.ar",`

because curl will add it for you as long as the url is correct. pretty much the ONLY time you need (and should) set the `Host:`-header manually is when you have DNS issues, you can't trust your DNS, or the DNS lookup time is so slow that you can't take the performance hit, all those scenarios are exceedingly rare, and most often it's just a rookie mistake.

Comment: Beautifully explained, and the extra bits of information were very welcome. Thanks!